# is there a function in printf family that returns a portion of the string?

Tags: c, printf

I mean this usage:

```
sprintf_with_start_pos(out_variable, 3, "format_str %s %i etc...", var1, var2);
```

and such function should withheld returning output until it arrives at position 3.
I know I can create this effect making my own buffer and then copy from that, but I wonder if is there in c a one liner for this ?

Comment: Position 3 in what sense? Do you want to print the first 3 characters? That's done using `%.3s`.

Comment: What do you mean by withholding output?

Comment: no I want to print from 3rd character onwards

Comment: @rsk82 Then you pass `var1 + 3` to the function.

Comment: ..after checking that there are at least three chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

test.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    char* var1 = "1234567";
    char buffer[50];
    sprintf(buffer, "%s", &var1[2]);

    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    printf("%.3s\n", buffer);
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc test.c 
$ ./a.out 
34567
345
```